# Text validation on a webpage where multiple elements have the same label

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the following code as part of a test:

```
if page.text.include? "Provide your details"
  go_and_enter_details
end
```

The webpage has multiple elements labelled `h2`, including the one that's being checked for content.

This error is returned:

```
Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching css "h2" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
```

How can get Ruby/Cucumber/Capybara to identify whether the page contains the text I need to check?

Comment: Depending on the HTML, you might be able to use the [`within`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#within-instance_method) method to target the element.

Comment: That error is not coming from your `page.text.include? ...`  line - so I assume its coming from your `go_and_enter_details` method?  If so show that method and exactly where the error is coming from.  Also, by using  page.text.include? you are bypassing Capybaras waiting behavior which can lead to flaky tests on dynamic pages.  If you use `page.has_text? "Provide your details"` then capybara will wait a bit to see if the text shows up.  If you are intentionally not wanting the waiting behavior then get into the habit of using `has_text? 'abc', wait: false` to make it clear it's intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various options:

- if the element you want to fill is the first one in the page, you can use [first element](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method)

  ```
  first('YOUR ELEMENT').click
  ```
- you can use [within](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Awithin), so you can tell capybara where to find your element (for example, in a `div`)

  ```
  within('body > div > div') do
   #find your element and do your work
  end
  ```
- you can use the `CSS selector` or the `XPath` of your element